# Can I test for memory leaks with Ranorex?

Tags: ranorex, memory-leaks

Is there any way to test my application for memory leaks with Ranorex?

Ranorex is a tool for integration testing. So I am not sure if this is the right place. On the other hand, it appears logical to me to test the integration of components for any memory leaks that could occur, and it makes sense to do so in typical use cases which I model with test cases.
Can you suggest other tools, or additional tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very interesting question.

I do not think there is a specific button in Ranorex that is called "Memory leak detection".

Detecting memory leak is a rather complex procedure that involves:

1. Produce a string of re-producible actions that may cause memory leak
2. Observe if the system memory depletes over time
3. Gradually remove one factor at a time to isolate the root cause(s)

Ranorex, as a test automation tool, I guess it can provide you with automated testing actions but how exactly to detect a memory leak, it varies from one application to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope to find a general way to programmatically detect an increase in memory consumption and incorporate it into a code module. I think step 3 is part of an analysis after a detection, and does not have to be automated.

Answer (score 1):

We were testing some memory leaks with the ranorex on eclipse based application with sleak.
Basically we were running few steps over and over and sometimes checked the sleak, if there are any uncleaned handles or other resources.

Ranorex can help you do the boring repeating part, but you must know how to identify the memory leaks. And that is technology dependant.